# How to get two different boxes inlined

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have an object tagged box and an iFrame, this is one example of what I want the code to do

```
[boz] [box] [box]
```

But this is what I get.

```
[box]
[box]
[box]
```

CSS:

```
.stream {
   display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stream">


        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
          height="350"
          width="390" 
          id="live_embed_player_flash"
          data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=username"
          bgcolor="#000000">
          <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
          <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
          <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
          <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
          <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=username&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" />
        </object>

             <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/username" 
              style="padding:2px 0px 4px; 
              display:block; width:345px; 
              font-weight:normal; 
              font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline; 
              text-align:center;">Watch live video from username on www.twitch.tv
             </a>


        <iframe 
          frameborder="0" 
          scrolling="no" 
          id="chat_embed" 
          src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=username&popout_chat=true" 
          height="350" 
          width="300">
        </iframe>
</div>
```

Anyone who have a solution?

Comment: try .stream object{display:inline-block;} or .stream object{float:left}

Comment: element in stream should be formated as inline boxes: .stream a, .stream object,.stream iframe{ display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;}

Comment: @otherDewi - float is tested, no succsess

Comment: @GCyrillus - Didn't work as planed. Every box is vertical now, not horisontal. As what i'm aiming for.

Comment: <table>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
won't work ether

Comment: @QuestionGiver , well remove the display:block on your <a> tag , see my answer and codepen demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my comment was not totally understood :)

```
 .stream a, 
.stream object,
.stream iframe{ 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LHwfj

Works if you remove the `display:block` in inline-style of `<a>` tag .

edit:
to make sure they keep on one line, you may add:

```
.stream {white-space:nowrap;} 
.stream * {white-space:normal;}
```

Comment: you want to center them ? : .stream {text-align:center;} , justify them ? : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nrbDl

Comment: How is it not working when this solution works as what you've described as wanted behavior?

Comment: if you have not enough width, then set : .stream {white-space:nowrap;} .stream * {white-space:normal;}

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Promblem after `{display: block;}` was too much width.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting inconsistent results is because you have defined `display: block;` for the `a` element inline.
Remove it, add a class to all the children elements and then use `.class {display: inline-block}`.

[See a sample Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LhyE/).